# Mathematical proof of a combined hash function

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

I´ve just started with crypto and I am trying to solve an exercise sheet. I am, however, not good at mathematical proofs and got a bit stuck on a certain - probably easy - question:

I´ve got three hash functions:

- $H_1:=  \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^a$
- $H_2:=  \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^b$
- $H_3:=\{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^b$

And I have to proof that: If at least one of $H_1, H_2, H_3$ are collision resistant $M:=  \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^{a+b}$ for  $M:= H_1(x)||H_2(x)||H_3(x)$ is collision resistant, too.

Intuitively I would say that $H_2$ and $H_3$ are not collision resistant, since they are shortened to the same length $b$.

I have started with assuming that $M$ is not collision resistant by changing the definition to:

$h(x_1) = h(x_2) = h(x_3) $  for a triplet $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

But I am not quite sure, if this is the correct way to do it.

Can I even proof it in one go? Or do I need several steps - like proofing $H_2 = H_3$ first?

Comment: I'd start with the definition of "collision resistant". Do you have a definition for that from the textbook or class notes?

Comment: Also, in your notation, you have that the range of $M$ is $\{0,1\}^{a+b}$, should that be $a+2b$?

Comment: I´ve got one from the lecture notes.  It says: " A non-keyed hash function is an efficent function $H: M \to \ T$   And a collision of $H$ is a Tuple  $(m_0,m_1)$ with  $H(m_0) = H(m_1)$.  An it is resistant, if no "efficent" adversary A is known, that finds a collision."  This is the one I modified for the triplet.

Comment: And the range really is the one given.

Comment: I don't see how the range can be correct. The output of $H_1$ is $a$ bits long, the outputs of $H_2$ and $H_3$ are $b$ bits long each. So if you concatenate them, you should end up with $a+b+b$ (or $a+2b$) bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the issue of output length I mention in the comments, you should be able to prove this without intermediate steps. Here is an outline of how I would do it.

1. Without loss of generality let one particular hash function be the one that is collision resistant. It doesn't matter which one. Say $H_3$.
2. Assume that $M$ is not collision resistant. This means, you can find $m_0\neq m_1$ such that $M(m_0)=M(m_1)$.
3. Show how this would lead to a collision in $H_3$ directly. This leads to a contradiction, so $M$ must be collision resistant.

This is a [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).

Comment: Now I got it. =) Thank you.  (And I´ll ask my tutor about the issue you mentioned.)